# How to combine search Filters in python LDAP?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-ldap

While accessing LDAP data , I am continuously receiving the `Size Limit Exceeded` error.

One of the solutions presented on google asked for much tighter search Filters.

How is it possible to combine two or more search filters in python LDAP ? 
Using the suggested `(|(filter1)(filter2))` is producing an error.

Here is the query :

```
baseDn = "ou=active, ou=employees, ou=people, o=xxxxx.com";
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
#retrieve Certain attributes
retrieveAttributes = ["manageruid","manager","cn"]
search_query = raw_input("Enter the query :")
#This searchFilter needs to be more specific
searchFilter = "city=" + "Bangalore"

try :
   ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDn, searchScope, searchFilter,   retrieveAttributes)
   result_set = []
   while 1:
       result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
       if(result_data == []):
           break
       else:
           if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
               result_set.append(result_data)
       #print result_set
       print len(result_set)   

except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
```

While trying to combine search filters :
This error comes.

```
 File "practice.py", line 33
    search_filter = (&("city=Bangalore")("manageruid=278586"))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which error? How does your actual query look like?

Comment: The code doesn't match the error message.

Comment: Yes,but I mentioned in the beginning that if I need to use tighter filters to stop "Size Limit Exceeded" error. But if I try to combine the search filters ,it gives the error given above [ "invalid syntax" ]

Comment: But you're not showing HOW you are trying to combine them, which is where the error seems to be

Answer (score 9):

I think `search_filter` has to be a string. Have you tried this?

```
search_filter = "(&(city=Bangalore)(manageruid=278586))"
```